# Downsides to multiple Realm files/databases?

Tags: android, realm

Most examples just use Realm.getDefaultConfiguration() for all their storage and access. I am wondering if there are any downsides (or advantages, even) to using different Realm files for each class? I know I don't have to, but the structure of my library (no good way to check if Realm has been initialized) makes me want to have a separate Realm file (or configuration) in different places.

It seems like it might have advantages of allowing me to specify different schemas and migrations, too. I know I *can* do this, but is there any reason not to?

Comment: well just keep in mind they are completely separate

Comment: Well...of course. I don't need data from configuration A in configuration B.

Answer (score 2):

Using different Realms helps separate concerns particularly around security. This becomes more relevant when using the Realm Mobile Platform with the backend Realm Object Server because Realms can be shared between different users and with different permissions. For instance, in a shopping app you may have a catalog realm that is read-only, a realm for the user's shopping cart which is private but shared between devices, and a shopping list realm which could be shared between members of the family.

If you are just using the Realm Mobile Database you could still use separate realms for security. Such as using an in-memory or encrypted realm for sensitive data and a separate realm for less critical data.

Comment: So far the only collaboration implementations I have seen is when someone uses a Realm with the same credentials. There is no app showing how someone could collaborate on a shared Realm, since every user on an Object server acquires credentials for his own Realm. So far I could not find a way in the docs to search eg for others users or anything else that lives outside the Realm I have authenticated for

Answer (score 1):

You can construct a different Realm for each different class. That's mostly a design decision on your own end if you feel that is appropriate.

When it comes to Realm Mobile Platform each realm instance begins syncing once you attempt to access it. The app will try to download that entire realm and try to keep it in sync. You may not want to download your app's entire collection of one class. Just because it is of a same class doesn't mean it's pertinent for that user to start syncing it.

For example, you may have a project management tool that has multiple boards full of multiple tasks. Each board can be a realm, with a `class Task`. If you try to access one realm, it's better to just sync that subset of Tasks rather than your entire domain's set of tasks then attempting to do a filter on it.

I would try to compartmentalize different realms as multiples databases of each with their own idea, own user-ownership or concern rather than saying that you should have a realm per type of class.